# Cannot specify directories for testing after upgrading to rails 5.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, minitest

I upgraded from `rails 5.1.1` to `rails 5.2.0`. My process was the following:

- Upgraded the rails gems and resolved dependency issues
- Looked at the [railsdiff between 5.1.1 and 5.2.0](http://railsdiff.org/5.1.1/5.2.0) and updated files as needed

Everything looks to be working well except I noticed some odd behavior within my test suite

- running the command `rails test test/system` is not running my system tests at all.  It runs all of my other tests (policies, services, models, jobs), but does not run my system tests.

  - Strangely: running a specific system test file, ex: `rails test test/system/comment_test.rb` works.
- Running specific directories of tests no longer works.  For example, previously I could run `rails test test/policies`, `rails test test/models`, and `rails test test/services` and it would only run tests in those directories.  This is no longer working.  Instead it just runs all of tests (except the system tests).

Any idea what changed between `rails 5.1.1` and `rails 5.2.0` that is causing this behavior?  Or, perhaps I am just missing something?

According to the [Rails Guides Testing Rails Applications: 2.7 The Rails Test Runner](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-rails-test-runner), it states that one should be able to run tests on a per-directory basis:

> You can also run an entire directory of tests by providing the path to the directory.

Expected behavior:

`rails test` => run entire test suite

`rails test test/system` => run all tests in the system directory

`rails test test/models` => run only the tests in the models directory

**Reproducing the Behavior**

I can reproduce the behavior with the following commands:

```
rails new test_app         # create demo app
cd test_app                # cd into app
rails g scaffold user name # scaffold user
rake db:migrate            # migrate
rails test test/system/    # Expect to run system tests but does not (scaffold creates 4 system tests)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `rails -T` you can see the available tasks.  The two relevant ones to this questions are

```
rails test          # Runs all tests in test folder except system ones
rails test:system   # Run system tests only
```

from which we can see `rails test` won't run system tests.  For that you need to run `rails test:system`, iirc correctly you can run all tests with `rails test:system test`